# Pass null primary key with jOOQ to have it set by the database

Tags: java, postgresql, dropwizard, jooq

For a REST service, I receive an object to persist in the database.  I want to prevent the user from setting the id.  Instead, the database should assign the value automatically from a sequence, like Postgresql's SERIAL.

If I try to null out the id in the jOOQ generated record, the database will error out when I try to store it.

Here's the relevant DDL.

```
CREATE TABLE todo (
  id SERIAL PRIMARY KEY,
  title TEXT,
  url TEXT
);
```

Here's the relevant code.  Full code at [todo-backend](https://github.com/jschaf/tododrop/blob/415861fb1d2f2ecf531d6da9beefc17dcd6ae738/src/main/java/tododrop/TodoResource.java#L29).

```
@POST
public Todo addTodo(Todo todo, @Context DSLContext db) {
    final TodoRecord todoRecord = db.newRecord(TODO, todo);

    // This errors out, violates not-null constraint on DB
    todoRecord.setId(null);

    todoRecord.store();

    todoRecord.setUrl("http://localhost:8080/" + todoRecord.getId());
    todoRecord.store();

    return db.selectFrom(TODO)
            .where(TODO.ID.eq(todoRecord.getId()))
            .fetchOneInto(Todo.class);
}
```

#### Versions

- dropwizard 0.8.5
- jOOQ 3.7.2
- Postgres 9.5
- Java 1.8

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Some databases allow `NULL` values in keys. Or perhaps, you might have a trigger that listens to `NULL` values being set on primary keys.

This is why jOOQ cannot assume that your intention for this call is to set `ID` to `DEFAULT`. jOOQ will assume that you really want `NULL` to be set in `INSERT` or `UPDATE` statements:

```
todoRecord.setId(null);
```

Instead, write

```
todoRecord.changed(TODO.ID, false);
```

See [`Record.changed(Field, boolean)`](http://www.jooq.org/javadoc/latest/org/jooq/Record.html#changed-org.jooq.Field-boolean-)